# Partition Shows Wrong Size

Tags: windows, partitioning, display

I had been having the small size issue on my drive C (where Windows XP is installed). So i decided to grow the size of this drive by using the software "EASEUS Partition Master 4.0 Home Edition".

I resided my other drive E having a total space of 42GB to give space to drive C using above software. I allocated about 10GB more space to C drive from E. But during the process, the software gave the following error.

"Update system information failed"

So the process did not succeed. Now the problem is that my drive E shows only the total space of 11GB whereas it was actually 42GB. Drive along with all its files and folders is accessible but only wrong size. It shows wrong 11GB even from Disk Management option. Where did my other size go?

How to solve this problem?
How to I recover the rest of size of my drive E?

**Edit: OS: WinXP, NTFS formats**

Thanks

Comment: My problem was solved by using this great piece of software: http://www.geeksdo.com/extend-c-drive-pc-acronis.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally try [GParted](https://gparted.org), I have successfully used this in the past with hard drives that show wrong/incorrect information.

A scan should show the correct information, if it doesn't, start by shrinking the drive slightly (even if only by 1MB) and this should basically correct the drive and make it show the correct information, then using [GParted](https://gparted.org), you can set it to however you want.

Comment: the data has become unallocated, how do i reallocate it?

Comment: I am a bit unsure what you mean by unallocated, if you simply mean RAW, you should be able to use Gparted to reallocate it.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better.

Answer (score 1):

First - before you go any further make a backup of your XP install. The I would try using a Linux live CD (like ubuntu). You can use the partition manager there to examine and hopefully fix your partition sizes. Hopefully the missing space is simply unallocated space.

Comment: yes, that is true, the missing space is unallocated, how to reallocate it please?

Answer (score 1):

You better try using Partition Magic(DOS based).

Comment: the data has become unallocated, how do i reallocate it?

Comment: To larger extent; Partition Magic has the ability to recover corrupted partitions, even unallocated space (if partition table is corrupted)!!